# Android EditText vs TextView

Tags: android, android-view

I am developing an application where all controls are custom and added dynamically. I can already add a label (which extends TextView) and an Image (which extends ImageView). Now I am trying to add a Text box (Which should be extending an EditText). I follow exactly the same procedure as for other views, in fact initial setup is the same, but I keep getting Runtime exception for EditText: "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare();"

Now, when I change this TextBox to extend TextView instead of an EditText, it works without any problems. 
The issue I think might be that either I am possibly not setting a property it expects me to provide(which I am not aware of) or could be something to do with context which is passed from separate class (which is also strange because it works with TextView and ImageView).
Here is my Text box code:

```
public class MyCustomTextBoxView extends EditText {

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

public MyCustomTextBoxView(Context context){
    super(context);
    setLayout();
}

   //...some other methods here...

private void setLayout(){
    //setting default values
    setLines(1);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(DPSHelper.getDPSValue(100), DPSHelper.getDPSValue(30));
    setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Here is my Application Context class:

```
    public class AppContext extends Application {

    private static Context appContext;
   @Override 
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      appContext = getApplicationContext();
  }
    public static Context get(){
        return appContext;
    }
}
```

Here id how I create the view from another class:

```
MyCustomTextBoxView view = new MyCustomTextBoxView(AppContext.get());
```

I've been trying to fix his for a few hours now, no idea what I am doing wrong.

Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shearwater.tabletapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="helpers.AppContext"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity />
...
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Packages included:

```
import helpers.AppContext;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import models.base.ComponentData;
import models.components.ImageBoxModel;
import models.components.SimpleLabelModel;
import models.components.SingleLineTextBoxModel;
import models.containers.HubLayoutContainerModel;
import views.HubLayoutContainerView;
import views.ImageBoxView;
import views.SimpleLabelView;
import views.SingleLineTextBoxView;
import android.view.View;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import controllers.HubLayoutContainerController;
import controllers.ImageBoxController;
import controllers.SimpleLabelController;
import controllers.SingleLineTextBoxController;
import enums.EControl;
```

Comment: Add log message here..

Comment: Try using CallerActivity.this instead of AppContext.get()...

Comment: Log message: 
11-18 13:07:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(8475): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()11-18 13:07:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(8475):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
11-18 13:07:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(8475):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
11-18 13:07:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(8475):  at android.widget.Editor$UserDictionaryListener.<init>(Editor.java:3875)
11-18 13:07:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(8475):  at android.widget.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:193)

Comment: can you show your menifest file here and also packages you have imported in your java class

Comment: @umair.ali I can't see the opportunity to use an activity context because all views are created first and added to a collection, which is then passed to another view to display. The reason for that is that I need to create different views and I don't know in advance what they are. Parent view can be then added to different activities.

Comment: @QadirHussain edited to show those

Comment: @etilia please show your pakackge names. like package com.your.package in your java file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. The issue was that I was creating all required views in AsyncTask before returning them to the main Activity to render. 
And for some reason I could create TextView, but not EditText (which extends TextView) and error was when initialising the editor. I added Looper.prepare() to doInBackground() for now as it looked like the best option for what I need to achieve.

Comment: You mention "EditView" in both your question and your answer. There's no such thing. I assume you mean "EditText"?

Comment: @RenniePet, yes, it is EditText indeed. Thanks for pointing that out. (edited)